# Change stock availability of products based on qty

Tags: magento-1.9, database, inventory, query

I'm looking for a query to get all my products that have "qty > 2 and 'stock availability = 0'" and change the stock availability to 1.

A crash on my inventory update routine did a mess on my inventory and there are more than 7000 products, impossible to check one by one. :(

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I ran this queries:

```
SELECT p.sku, s.qty, s.min_qty, s.is_in_stock FROM "catalog_inventory_table" s inner join catalog_product_entity p on s.product_id = p.entity_id where s.qty

SELECT p.sku, s.product_id, s.qty, s.min_qty, s.is_in_stock FROM "catalog_inventory_table" s inner join catalog_product_entity p on s.product_id = p.entity_id where s.qty >= s.min_qty

UPDATE "catalog_inventory_table" SET is_in_stock = 1 WHERE qty >= min_qty AND qty > 0;
```

where "catalog_inventory_table" is my catalog inventory table name :)